# Intersecção de palavras com dicionários em Python

Tags: python

Olá!

No livro do Wendel Melo, *Introdução ao Universo da Programação com Python*, tentei realizar o último exercício, mas não estou conseguindo.

**Enunciado**:

Faça um programa que leia três strings do usuário e liste cada palavra
que apareça ao menos uma vez em uma das strings. Cada palavra só
deve ser listada uma única vez, e junto a ela os textos em que a mesma
aparece. Seu programa deve contemplar uma função que receba as strings
lidas e retorne um dicionario onda as chaves são compostas pelas palavras
e os itens são conjuntos indicando os textos em que cada chave (palavra)
aparece.

**Exemplo**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz este código, ele apresenta os respectivos itens do texto1, texto2 e texto3, porém eu não sei como seguir, porque as palavras se repetem ao decorrer do código. Creio que uma boa solução seria utilizando o *intersection*, método dos conjuntos, em alguma parte do código, porém eu não sei como transformar essa interseção nas palavras *texto1*, *texto2* e *texto3*, pois o método só retornará o elemento da interseção e não o conjunto onde ele se encontra. Desde já, agradeço quem me ajudar.

```
def tDicionario(texto1, texto2, texto3):
    palavras = {}
    
    
    for palavra in texto1:
        print('{}: '.format(palavra))
        
    for palavra in texto2:
        print('{}: '.format(palavra))
        
    for palavra in texto3:
        print('{}: '.format(palavra))
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    texto1 = input('Entre com o texto 1: ').split()
    texto2 = input('Entre com o texto 2: ').split()
    texto3 = input('Entre com o texto 3: ').split()
    
    print('Listagem de palavras: ')
    print(tDicionario(texto1, texto2, texto3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais fácil é usando um dicionário em Python onde cada uma de suas **chaves** representa uma **palavra**, e o seu **valor** associado é uma **lista dos números dos textos** em que uma dada palavra aparece. Utilizar conjuntos também seria viável, mas acredito ser mais simples de seguir a lógica do programa dessa forma.

Também fica mais simples se você pedir o input e logo em seguida colocar os dados pra dentro do dicionário, ao invés de pedir os inputs separadamente. Se você fizer isso dentro de um loop, fica fácil de checar se a palavra já consta no dicionário, ou se ela já apareceu mais de uma vez na mesma frase. Isso inclusive trivializa a generalização do seu programa: dá para pedir um número arbitrário de frases pro usuário apenas modificando uma linha.

Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
# Iniciamos com o dicionário vazio
resultado = {}

# Número de frases a pedir para o usuário
numero_de_frases = 3

for n in range(numero_de_frases):
    # n começa de 0, adicionamos 1 e convertemos 
    # para string para simplificar nossa vida 
    num_texto = str(n + 1)
    
    # Pega input do usuário
    texto = input(f'Entre com o texto {num_texto}: ')
    lista_de_palavras = texto.split()
    
    # Itera sobre lista de palavras
    for palavra in lista_de_palavras:
        # Se a palavra é inédita no dicionário, cria uma nova lista
        if palavra not in resultado:
            resultado[palavra] = list()
        # Pega a lista de números dos textos onde a palavra aparece
        lista_num_textos = resultado[palavra]
        # Se a palavra já apareceu no texto, pulamos a linha abaixo
        # (evita entradas repetidas quando a palavra está duplicada)
        if num_texto not in lista_num_textos:
            lista_num_textos.append(num_texto)

# Itera sobre dicionário e mostra os resultados
for palavra, lista_num_textos in resultado.items():
    string_num_textos = ', '.join(lista_num_textos)
    print(f'A palavra "{palavra}" aparece no(s) texto(s): {string_num_textos}')
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a terceira frase do enunciado da questão...

> *Seu programa deve contemplar uma **função** que receba as strings lidas e retorne um dicionário onda as chaves são compostas pelas palavras e os itens são conjuntos indicando os textos em que cada chave (palavra) aparece.*

...podemos implementar uma **função** para resolver a questão.

Para montarmos a referida função podemos utilizar algumas lógicas. Neste caso, podemos utilizar a seguinte lógica:

1. Capturar os três textos sugeridos e armazena-los em uma lista;
2. Enviar esta lista como parâmetro para a função que montará o dicionário;
3. Montar o dicionário;
4. Exibir os resultados idênticos ao sugerido na questão.

Pois bem, um dos códigos possíveis para esta lógica é:

```
def localiza_palavra(lista_textos):
    o = range(1, len(lista_textos) + 1)
    dicionario = dict()
    for texto, posicao in zip(lista_textos, o):
        for palavra in texto:
            if palavra not in dicionario:
                dicionario[palavra] = list()
            r = dicionario[palavra]
            if posicao not in r:
                r.append(posicao)
    return dicionario


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = list()
    for i in range(1, 4):
        lista.append(input(f'Entre com o texto {i}: ').split())

    resultado = localiza_palavra(lista)

    print('Listagem de palavras:')
    for key, item in resultado.items():
        print(f'{f"{key}:":<10}', *[f'texto {x},' for x in item])
```

Observe que ao executarmos o código, devemos digitar os três textos. Esses textos são capturados como lista e, em seguida, armazenados em outra lista.

Depois disso esta lista será enviada como parâmetro para a função **localiza_palavra()**.
Chagando lá o primeiro bloco `for`, com ajuda da função `zip()`, percorrerá simultaneamente as listas `lista_textos` - formada por todos os textos digitados - e `o` - formada pelas ordens dos textos.

Em seguida o segundo bloco `for` percorrerá cada **palavra** do **texto** atual e, com ajuda do bloco `if` será verificado se a respectiva **palavra** não está contida no dicionário. Caso a palavra não esteja no dicionário, o dicionário receberá como chave a respectiva palavra cujo valor é uma lista.

Esta lista será montada com as posições dos respectivos textos.

O segundo bloco `if` verificará se a **posicao** atual não pertence à r - lista formada pelas posições. Caso, a posição não se encontre em `r`, a posição será adicionada.

Terminada todas as interações possíveis, os resultados serão exibidos.

A exibição dos valores é realizada pelo último bloco `for` do código.

A última linha de código...

```
print(f'{f"{key}:":<10}', *[f'texto {x},' for x in item])
```

...executa o seguinte:

1. Exibe o valor da chave (key) acompanhada de " : " no canto esquerdo de um total de 10 espaços;
2. Exibe o desempacotamento de um lista montada por list comrehension, onde cada elemento  é formado pela palavra `texto` seguida do número de ordem do texto.